# Запоминание покупок игрока

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу узнать как я могу "запоминать" покупки игрока.
Есть магазин в котором игрок должен покупать скины(сама покупка уже реализована).

//Скрипт сильно упростил ,но логика та же.

```
public int Money



public void ChangeSkin(int Skins)
{
    switch (Skins)
        {         
            case 1:
             if (Money >= 10)
             {
               Логика покупки
             }
             break;
    case 2:
             if (Money >= 10)
             {
               Логика покупки
             }
             break;
    case 3:
             if (Money >= 10)
             {
               Логика покупки
             }
             break;
    case 4:
             if (Money >= 10)
             {
               Логика покупки
             }
             break;
        }
}
```

Как я могу после покупки "запоминать", что игрок уже это купил?
После запуска игры в Start() я уже должен знать все купленные предметы  для изменения на них иконок.

Comment: Как вариант - в параметрах игрока сделать список ID сделанных покупок.

Comment: У тебя ведь есть код который при входе вспоминает сколько у игрока денег и присваивает Money ?! Там же вспоминаем переменную Buyed

Comment: @santavital извините, но не `Buyed` ,а `Bought` раз на то пошло)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для сохранения значений, в том числе и между заходами в игру, в Unity3D есть такой класс как **[PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)**. Он позволяет *сохранять* значения **(int, string, float)**, *просматривать* их, *удалять* и *перезаписывать*.

В логике покупки вы можете написать следующее *(**имя ключа** - название под которым вы сохранили/сохраните значение покупки - 1 или непокупки - 0 конкретного предмета/скина)*:

```
//code...
case 1:
     if (Money >= Цена)
     {
         if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(имя ключа)) // существует ли эта переменная
         {
             if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt(имя ключа) == 0) // не куплено
             {
                 /*покупка*/
                 Money -= skin.Price;
                 GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite1;
                 PlayerPrefs.SetInt(имя ключа, 1); // куплен
             }
             else { /*сообщение о том что предмет уже куплен*/ }
         }
         else
         {
             /*покупка*/
             Money -= skin.Price;
             GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite1;
             PlayerPrefs.SetInt(имя ключа, 1); // куплен
         }
     }
break;
//code...
```

Также я советую вам сделать отдельный класс Skin. Его приблизительный код:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Skin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public readonly string Name; // задать в редакторе либо вне класса [УНИКАЛЬНОЕ ДЛЯ КАЖДОГО СКИНА]
    public int Price;            // задать в редакторе либо вне класса
    public Sprite SkinSprite;    // задать в редакторе либо вне класса
    public bool WasBuy
    {
        get
        {             
            if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(Name + "_wasbuy")) // существует ли эта переменная            
                return PlayerPrefs.GetInt(Name + "_wasbuy");
            else
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt(Name + "_wasbuy", 0);
                return false;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(Name + "_wasbuy", Convert.ToInt32(value));
        }
    }
}
```

И тогда метод ChangeSkin будет иметь следующий вид:

```
// using System.Linq
void ChangeSkin(string Name, Skin[] allSkins) // allSkins - все скины для данного предмета
{
    try
    {
        var skin = allSkins.First((skin) => skin.Name == Name);
        if (skin.WasBuy)
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = skin.SkinSprite;
        else if (Money >= skin.Price)
        {
            Money -= skin.Price;
            skin.WasBuy = true;
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = skin.SkinSprite;
        }
        else
            // нехватает денег

    }
    catch(System.Exception)
    {
        // скин не существует
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй хранить файл с покупками.Можно даже количество туда добавить.Пример:
Класс который будет сохраняться:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ShopData
{ 
public int ID;
public int Count;
}
```

К примеру,потом с помощью классов JsonUtility считывай обратно в файл и записывай в него.И всегда сможешь знать,кто что купил.

Comment: Это юнити. А значит кросплатформенность. Я не думаю что работать с сериализацией хорошая идея, могут возникнуть непредвиденные проблемы.

Comment: Ну PlayerPrefs уж точно не подойдёт.Если товара будет много.И судя по вопросам,человека интересует почти 100% платформы: Windows,Mac,IOS,Android , на них проблем с сериализацией и хранением данных не будет.А иначе из полностью кроссплатформенных решений,то это однозначно хранить данные на сервере=) Создавать человеку аккаунт и по запросу возвращать ответ с данными.И почему будут проблемы с кросплатформеностью?ФБ тоже к примеру ответы диплинков возвращает json массивом (тоже сериализация своего рода).

Comment: Мне тоже решение с PlayerPrefs не нравится. Я в этом солидарен.

Answer (score 0):

Лично мне решение KuzCode не понравилось.

Причина проста: можно игрушку хакать тупо через блокнот. Если это не играет роли - то плевать и можно использовать и его подход. Но т.к. ответ, все таки, решает вопрос, то минуса он не заслуживает :)

Если же важно что бы покупки невозможно(окей, менее легко) было хакнуть - нужно использовать запрос на сервер который будет подтверждать что этот вот чувак купил вот эту вот покупку. Можно через простой http реквест и информация которая кодировалась бы под неким ключем, но передавалась, например, чрез JSON.

Делать запрос на старте программы. И тогда уже обновлять данные локально.

Но, подозреваю, что возможно это же есть в каких-то апи магазинов. Вроде эплстора или же плеймаркета. Сам я с таким не сталкивался и не работал, но в документации поискал бы информацию про это однозначно. Как минимум с него можно тягнуть информацию о юзере. Какой-то айдишник. Что бы привязывать конкретного юзера к игре, а не девайс.